# Is there a default button style on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uibutton

I am programatically creating views, when I add a button with a title all I see is some text and a clear background.  Is there a way to get a default looking button with rounded corners, borders, and pressed states without having to specific every property manually?

If the latter is the case, is there a style guide somewhere so I can get default-look buttons?

Comment: As others have pointed out, there is the 'round rect' button. Visually, it is extremely lame (especially compared to the ones used by the system and  Apple's apps). The best is to have your designer make some cool images and use UIButtonTypeCustom. Perhaps there's some QuartzCore tricks you can use to spice up UIButtonTypeRoundRect?

Comment: Good feedback. We'll likely skin everything with custom images at a later point, but for now this good enough.

Comment: Yeah, gets you up un running. You can always 'redecorate' once your basic functionality is working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];                     
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 30, 30);
button.titleLabel.text = @"A Button";
[self.view addSubview: button];
```

Here's what each line does:

- The first line sets the button type to rounded rect, but it could also be `UIButtonTypeCustom`, `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`, `UIButtonTypeInfoLight`, `UIButtonTypeInfoDark`, `UIButtonTypeContactAdd`.
- The second line sets the frame of the button, which is where it should be located on the screen and the button's height and width.
- The third line sets the text of the button to "A Button".
- The fourth and last line adds the button to the screen.

The button will look like this:

[image]

Comment: So that's where you set the button type.  Exactly what I was looking for, works like a charm!

Comment: @rhooligan - Just a note: UIButtons also have a property called `buttonType`, but this property is readonly, so you can't say `myButton.buttonType = UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```